# Un-Install python totally and reinstall on mac?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

I had Python 2.7 and some previous versions in  `/Library/Python` folder. I recently tried installing Python 3.3, however it did not get installed properly.

I am getting run-time errors after trying to install Python 3.3:

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 6 but this version of numpy is 4
```

I tried upgrading numpy but it still gave the error.

I want to get back to Python 2.7. How do I revert it? How can I uninstall entire Python and reinstall only Python 2.7?

Other details:

- Now my `/Library/Python/` has 2.3, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7 folders but no 3.3 folder.
- Now my `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/versions` has 3.3 and 3.4 folders and no 2.7 folder.

Comment: To avoid those kind of issues you should install other versions of python using virtualenv. Otherwise you run the risk of messing up your other installations

Comment: I would have left your native python installation alone.  I highly recommend using anaconda to install any python environment, as they do not conflict with you native installation.

Comment: Yes I installed anaconda.. Seems to be working better now..